# Custom UITableViewCells are not being reused on UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

There seems to be a ton of questions on this but I am not able to use anyone else's answers so was hoping someone could review how I am doing this. I am trying to use.  I have two custom UITableViewCells which right now just have a BOOL property on them and thats it in the way of styling.

Within my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method based on what type of data is coming back I am styling my cells.  If the data is a "month" header its a long skinny looking cell and if its a "news item" its going to be a larger white looking cell.

[image]

When the table loads everything looks great but if I scroll down to create more cells and then scroll back up the cells are being recreated and eventually scrolling slows down because I am running out of memory.

When I set break points the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns nil so my cells are never reused which seems to be a problem.

In this picture you can see that cells are getting stacked on top of each other and messed up:

[image]

Here my my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *NewsCellIdentifer = @"NewsCellIdentifier";
    static NSString *MonthCellIdentifier = @"MonthCellIdentifier";


    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NewsItem *item = [self.newsArray objectAtIndex:row];

    if (item.IsMonth == YES)
    {
        NewsMonthUITableViewCell *cell = [self.mytableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MonthCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[NewsMonthUITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MonthCellIdentifier];
        }

        // This handles any other "date" cells to allow for different spacing styles.
        if (item.IsMonth)
        {
            UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 400, 20)];
            av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            av.opaque = NO;
            av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"month-bar-bkgd.png"];
            UILabel *monthTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 20)];;
            CGFloat font = 11.0f;
            monthTextLabel.font = [BVFont HelveticaNeue:&font];
            monthTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            monthTextLabel.font = [BVFont HelveticaNeue:&font];
            monthTextLabel.textColor = [BVFont WebGrey];
            monthTextLabel.text = item.Title;

            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:av];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:monthTextLabel];
        }

        return cell;

    }
    else
    {
        NewsUITableViewCell *cell = [self.mytableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NewsCellIdentifer];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[NewsUITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:NewsCellIdentifer];
        }

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,100)];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
        [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self NewsItemThumbnailView:item]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self NewsItemTextView:item]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self NewsItemCornerIconIndicatorView:item]];

        return cell;

    }

    return nil;

}
```

Thanks for any assistance or advice!

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Are you using Storyboards with dynamic prototypes? If so, check that each cells "Identifier" in the Attributes Inspector is set correctly. Also, if you are NOT using storyboards and dynamic prototypes, your code that creates and adds sub-views should go INSIDE your `if (cell==nil)` block.  My advice is to use Storyboards with dynamic prototypes and do the customisation in the cells in IB.

Comment: I am using Storyboard but I am not using Prototyped cells or designing my cells in storyboard. I just have my TableView dropped on the screen but programmatically doing the rest.

Comment: Robotic Cat, moving the code within the cell==nil block fixed it. If you post that as the answer I can mark it for you.

Comment: @RoboticCat: when you use prototype cells, there is no requirement of cell==nil condition, because we are allocating minimum one cell on the storyboard.with prototype cells this condition never been true

Comment: That's good to know Ravindra and why its probably better that I use that method of doing this going forward.

Comment: @Flea: Done. @Ravindra Bagale: As per Flea's comment he is using Storyboards but is NOT using dynamic prototype cells and so the `if (cell == nil)` block is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Storyboards WITHOUT dynamic prototypes then you need to place your code that creates and adds sub-views INSIDE your `if (cell==nil)` block. Otherwise all the sub-views are added again each time the tableview cell is re-used.

Going forwards, my advice is to use Storyboards with dynamic prototypes (with sub-classed UITableViewCells) and do the customisation in the cells in IB.

Answer (score 1):

cast your cells to Customcells,and use only tableView see below example.

```
   NewsMonthUITableViewCell *cell = (NewsMonthUITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MonthCellIdentifier];
  NewsUITableViewCell *cell =(NewsUITableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NewsCellIdentifer];
```

Use dynamic prototype cells , for prototype cells there is no requirement of cell allocation & check for proper cellIdentifier.

on storyboard create two prototype cells & give them different cellIdentifier, in your case NewsCellIdentifer & MonthCellIdentifier. be sure for the spelling of NewsCellIdentifer because you have missed `i` from NewsCellIdentifer.

Comment: Ravindra, thanks for the response. I just tried it but still have the same behavior.

Comment: remove self from tableView

Comment: i think its because of self.myTableView, remove it and use only tableView

Comment: Ravindra, by moving the code into the (cell == nill) block seems to have corrected the issue. I certainly appreciate your feedback on the other comments you made and will implement your suggestions to improve on this.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. You said your cell dequeuing is returning nil. Has this been confirmed with breakpoints or logs? Or is this a mere deduction from the images that you posted?

It would seem to me that there could be another culprit for the problem of cells stacking on top of each other and not being reused.

I can see that the whiteRoundedCornerView is created and added to the cell everytime you scroll through the cell. Even if this isn't the reason for your problem, it is definitely a problem. You are not creating cells properly. You must put this code into the if (cell == nil) block. In fact, almost all the code that lies outside of the block needs to go into it. Then any code that sets the text or image value should go outside the block. I see that someone has already made this suggestion but it has not satisfied you. I'll just emphasize again that it's still wrong and you need to fix this if you want to fix your app. (nice looking app by the way).

Also, if I may make a suggestion on other aspects of your code. You custom coded the headers and didn't use actual section headers. This is awefully odd to me. Also, you have a redundant "if (item.isMonth)" in there. Since one is already in the block of another, it will always be a month item.

Comment: Btw, if my post wasnt clear, the stacking of the whiteRoundedCornerView is what is causing those visual artifacts that you show in your screenshots.

Comment: Stupid refresh on my iPhone made me miss the fact that this already worked for you. And instead wrote up this long response.

Comment: Thanks eddieios, you are correct and I needed to put the code inside the (cell == nil) block! Thank you for taking the time to answer, I di up-tick your answer as helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on iOS 7 and storyboard while I never had this problem with the same code on elder Xcode-SDK versions, and trying lots of suggestions from stackoverflow, I couldn't fix it, and guess what?! Apple's [TableView Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) has the well-explained guide.
There's even no need to use `cell==nil`.

So I put the instructions here hoping it helps others:

To create a custom tableview cell using storyboard that would be reused properly, you can take two different approacesh. I personally prefer the first one which is more straightforward, but I put both solutions here.

***First Approach***

1. Create a project using the Master-Detail Application template and select the Use Storyboards option.
2. On the storyboard canvas, select the master view controller.
3. In the Identity inspector, verify that Class is set to the custom MasterViewController class.
4. Select the table view inside the master view controller.
5. In the Attributes inspector, verify that the Content pop-up menu is set to Dynamic Prototypes.
6. Select the prototype cell.
7. In the Attributes inspector, choose Custom in the Style pop-up menu.
8. Enter a reuse identifier in the Identifier text field.
   This is the same reuse identifier you send to the table view in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` message.
9. Choose Disclosure Indicator in the Accessory pop-up menu.
10. Drag objects from the Library onto the cell.
    For this example, drag two label objects and position them near the ends of the cell (leaving room for the accessory view).
11. Select the objects and set their attributes, sizes, and autoresizing characteristics.

An important attribute to set for the programmatic portion of this procedure is each object’s `tag` property. Find this property in the `View` section of the `Attributes inspector` and assign each object a unique integer.

Now write the code you would normally write to obtain the table view’s data. (For this example, the only data you need is the row number of each cell.) Implement the data source method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to create a new cell from the prototype and populate it with data, in a manner similar to this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    UILabel *label;

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NUMBER_OF_ROWS - indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

There are a few aspects of this code to note:

- The string identifier you assign to the prototype cell is the same string you pass to the table view in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.
- **Because the prototype cell is defined in a storyboard, the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method always returns a valid cell. You don’t need to check the return value against nil and create a cell manually.**
- **The code gets the labels in the cell by calling `viewWithTag:`, passing in their tag integers. It can then set the textual content of the labels.**

***Second Approach***

If you prefer not to use tags, you can use an alternative method for setting the content in the cell. Define a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass with outlet properties for the objects you want to set. In the storyboard, associate the new class with the prototype cell and connect the outlets to the corresponding objects in the cell.

*To use outlets for the custom cell content*

1. Add an Objective-C class named MyTableViewCell to your project.
2. Add the following code to the interface in `MyTableViewCell.h`:

   @interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *firstLabel;
   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *secondLabel;
   @end
3. Add the following code to the implementation in `MyTableViewCell.m`:

   @synthesize firstLabel, secondLabel;
4. Add the following line of code to the source file that implements the data source:

   #import "MyTableViewCell.h"
5. Use the `Identity inspector` to set the Class of the prototype cell to `MyTableViewCell`.
6. Use the Connections inspector to connect the two outlets in the prototype cell to their corresponding labels.
   [image]
7. Implement the data source method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

   cell.firstLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
   cell.secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NUMBER_OF_ROWS - indexPath.row];

   return cell;
   }
   ```

The code gains access to the labels in the cell using accessor methods (dot notation is used here). The code can then set the textual content of the labels.